# Wait for resource to be loaded with new swift concurrency features

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

Is it somehow possible to wait for resource to be loaded with new swift concurrency features. Here is an example:

```
enum ResourceState {
    case initial
    case loading
    case loaded
}

actor Resource {
    var state = ResourceState.initial

    func load() {
        // Load resource on background thread
        // ...
    }

    func doWithResource() {
        if state == .initial {
            load()
        }

        if state == .loaded {
            // Do !
        }

        if state == .loading {
            // How to wait for resource to be loaded???
            // Resource loading can be initiated from elsewhere
        }
    }

    // Same as , but with 
    func doWithResource() {
        if state == .initial {
            load()
        }

        if state == .loaded {
            // Do !
        }

        if state == .loading {
            // How to wait for resource to be loaded???
            // Resource loading can be initiated from elsewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Without async await I would use command pattern to store actions, queue them up and execute them when resource loads, but perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: You could make the load function async & returning `Bool` to check when it's done loading.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter I think that is the right direction, thanks. Can you provide a more detailed answer, please?

Comment: You can wait only on `async` function, so convert your load function into an `async` function. If it accepts a closure call back you can convert it using `withCheckedContinuation(function:_:)` or `withCheckedThrowingContinuation(function:_:)`.

Comment: We cannot be specific without seeing what `load` is doing. See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) for examples of converting methods to use new async-await patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Continuations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation) to suspend/wait for resource to be available. By using [`withCheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedcontinuation(function:_:)) you can store the continuations and resume all the continuations once your resource becomes available.

Have caution when you are using the continuation as resuming them more than once or not resuming them at all causes undefined runtime behaviors and errors:

> Resuming from a continuation more than once is undefined behavior. Never resuming leaves the task in a suspended state indefinitely, and leaks any associated resources. CheckedContinuation logs a message if either of these invariants is violated.

Also you can use [`withCheckedThrowingContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)) to support asynchronous wait with cancellation. For a sample implementation, you can look into this [`Future`](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/AsyncObjects/blob/main/Sources/AsyncObjects/Future.swift) actor I have created that provides similar functionality.